# How to make Clickable hyperlink on a PDF using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pdf, hyperlink

A table contains a list of 3 employees and 3-4 courses they are supposed to take respectively. My code creates individual PDFs for every employee in this table. First PDF will have list of 3 courses to be taken by Emp1, 2nd PDF will have list of 3 courses to be taken by Emp2 and so on.

**Code**

```
pip install fpdf

import pandas as pd
data = {'EmpNo': ['123','123','123','456','456', '456','456','789','789','789'],
'First Name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Danny', 'Danny', 'Danny'],
'Last Name': ['Doe', 'Doe' ,'Doe', 'Doe' ,'Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Roberts', 'Roberts', 'Roberts'],
'Activity Code': ['HR-CONF-1', 'HR-Field-NH-ONB','COEATT-2021','HR-HBK-CA-1','HR-WD-EMP','HR-LIST-1','HS-Guide-3','HR-WD-EMP','HR-LIST-1','HS-Guide-3'],
'URL' : ['www.hrconf1.com','www.hrfnhonb.com','www.coeatt.com','www.hrhbk.com', 'www.hrwdemp.com','www.hrl.com','www.hrconf1.com','www.hrconf1.com','www.hrconf1.com','www.hrconf1.com'],
'RegistrationDate': ['11/22/2021', '11/22/2021', '11/22/2021', '11/22/2021', '11/22/2021', '11/22/2021','11/22/2021', '11/22/2021', '11/22/2021','11/22/2021']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['EmpNo','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Activity Code', 'URL','RegistrationDate'])


from fpdf import FPDF


    
class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        # Arial bold 15
        self.set_font('Helvetica', 'B', 15)
        # Move to the right
        self.cell(80)            
        # Title
        self.cell(42, 2, 'Training Plan', 0, 0, 'C')
        # Line break
        self.ln(20)
    
        # Page footer
    def footer(self):
        # Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        self.set_y(-15)
        # Arial italic 8
        self.set_font('Helvetica', 'I', 8)
        # Page number
        self.cell(0, 10, 'Page ' + str(self.page_no()) + '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C')
        # Footer image First is horizontal, second is vertical, third is size

for EmpNo, data in df.groupby('EmpNo'):
    first_row = data.iloc[0] # Get first row of grouped dataframe

    # Instantiation of inherited class
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.alias_nb_pages()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Helvetica', '', 11)
    pdf.cell(80, 6, 'Employee ID: ' + str(EmpNo), 0, 1, 'L')
    pdf.ln(2.5)
    pdf.cell(80, 6, '', 0, 1, 'C')
    pdf.set_font('Helvetica', 'B', 13)
    pdf.cell(80, 6, 'Course Name', 0, 0, 'L')
    pdf.cell(40, 6, 'Course Date', 0, 0, 'L')
    pdf.cell(40, 6, 'Link', 0, 1, 'L')
    pdf.cell(80, 6, '', 0, 1, 'C')
    pdf.set_font('Helvetica', '', 8)

    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        pdf.set_font('Helvetica', '', 8)
        pdf.cell(80, 6, row['Activity Code'], 0, 0, 'L')
        pdf.cell(40, 6, row['RegistrationDate'], 0, 0, 'L')
        pdf.cell(40, 6, row['URL'], 0, 1, 'L')
        pdf.set_font('Helvetica', 'U', 8)
        pdf.set_font('Helvetica', 'B', 10)
        pdf.cell(80, 6, '', 0, 1, 'C')
        pdf.cell(80, 6, 'IF YOU REQUIRE ANY HELP, PLEASE CONTACT US', 0, 0, 'L')
        pdf.output(str(first_row['First Name']) + ' ' + str(first_row['Last Name'])+ '.pdf', 'F')
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

How can I make these links as Clickable links on the PDF such that it displays "Click Here" while the actual link is embedded as a Hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks @KJ, here the links are super lengthy and they are being cropped when exported into PDF, hence I wanted Click here link